# Not able to append dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am not able to append dataframe to already created dataframe.
Expecting output as below:

```
a    b
```

0   1    1
1   2    4
2  11  121
3  12  144

```
import pandas

def FunAppend(*kwargs):
    if len(kwargs)==0:
        Dict1={'a':[1,2],'b':[1,4]}
        df=pandas.DataFrame(Dict1)
    else:

        Dict1={'a':[11,12],'b':[121,144]}       
        dfTemp=pandas.DataFrame(Dict1)
        df=df.append(dfTemp,ignore_index=True)
    return df


df=FunAppend()
df=FunAppend(df)
print df
print "Completed"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying the global variable `df` inside the FunAppend function.

Python needs to be explicitly notified about this. Add inside the function:

```
global df
```

And it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As df is not defined when you go to the else case, although you did sent the df to the function in the form of  kwargs, so you can access to the df by typing `kwargs[0]`

Change this:

```
df=df.append(dfTemp,ignore_index=True)
```

To:

```
df=kwargs[0].append(dfTemp,ignore_index=True)
```